# How to create a two rows horizontal scroll in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to create something similar to the wrapped inside the blue box in the image below:

[image]

This is my current code:

Container

```
<ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
   <View style={styles.container}>
      {
         categories.map((category, index) => {
            return <CategoryCard key={index} category={category} navigation={navigation} />
         })
      }
   </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Category Card

```
const CategoryCard = ({ category, onPress }) => {

    return (
        <AppPressable
            style={styles.wrapper}
            onPress={onPress}
        >
            <View style={styles.nameWrapper}>
                <AppIcon
                    iconName={category.icon}
                    iconColor={category.color}
                    iconSize={24}
                    style={styles.icon}
                />
                <AppText style={styles.title}>{category.title}</AppText>
            </View>
        </AppPressable>
    )
}

export default CategoryCard
```

StyleSheet

```
const CategorySearchStyle = StyleSheet.create({

    wrapper: {
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginVertical: 5,
        marginRight: 7,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#d3d3d3'
    },

    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: "wrap",
        marginHorizontal: 15,
        marginBottom: 20
    },

    nameWrapper: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    title: {
        color: '#000000',
    },

    icon: {
        marginRight: 7
    }

});

export default CategorySearchStyle;
```

categories (array)

```
const categories = [
    {
        title: 'Arts, Crafts, And Collectibles',
        icon: 'palette',
        color: '#3D79C2'
    },
    {
        title: 'Baby',
        icon: 'human-child',
        color: '#FF5353'
    },
    {
        title: 'Beauty And Fragrances',
        icon: 'diamond-stone',
        color: '#1DD2AF'
    },
    {
        title: 'Books And Magazines',
        icon: 'book-open-variant',
        color: '#FE4080'
    },
    {
        title: 'Business To Business',
        icon: 'briefcase-variant',
        color: '#24A69A'
    },
    {
        title: 'Clothing, Accessories, And Shoes',
        icon: 'tshirt-crew',
        color: '#8E4162'
    },
    {
        title: 'Computers, Accessories, And Services',
        icon: 'devices',
        color: '#9A63C1'
    },
    {
        title: 'Education',
        icon: 'school',
        color: '#9A63C1'
    },

]

export default categories
```

This is what I have achieved so far:

[image]

It's only one row that is horizontal. I want it to be like two rows that can be scrolled horizontally.

Is .map enough or FlatList will do the trick?

Comment: Why don’t you split your categories array in two arrays and use two flatlist? (Since the data is not fetch remotely)

Answer (score 1):

Using FlatList instead of map you can implement it, Check below example or [snack.expo](https://snack.expo.dev/sRvqHzIdp)

```
<ScrollView
  horizontal
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  directionalLockEnabled={true}
  alwaysBounceVertical={false}
>
  <FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}
    numColumns={Math.ceil(categories.length / 2)}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={categories}
    directionalLockEnabled={true}
    alwaysBounceVertical={false}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.wrapper}>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }}
  />
</ScrollView>
```